# ldap authentication - active directory and php

Tags: php, active-directory, openldap

Iv'e seen many question related to Active Directory authentication through PHP.

And all of them rely on on ldap_bind().

My problem is that the server supports anonym ldap binding, so I can't do my test regarding this.

Is there a way to **specifcally check if both given username and password match values in AD** ?

I've seen there is a unicodePwd field in AD.

Many thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

in PHP you can try this:

```
// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding anonymously
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous failed...";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution : that can be done the same way (using ldap_bind) but being sure that username and password values are not empty

Hope it helps someone else.